# The number of logarithm applications to get from n below 1

Tags: logarithms, terminology, big-numbers, ackermann-function

Let $L(n)$ to be a number of logarithms that you need to apply on $n$ until you get below 1:

$$ 0 \leq \log\cdots\log n < 1 \\
\uparrow \\
L(n)\mbox{-times}
 $$

Is there a name for this function? It's clearly very very slowly growing. Is it perhaps somehow related to the [inverse Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse)?

Comment: What base is the logarithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known as the iterated logarithm function $\log^{*}(n)$, with a small modification. Note that we have that $\log^{*}(n)=0$ if $0 \leq n \leq 1$. However your $L(1)=1$. This will cause that $L(n) \neq \log^{*}(n)$ if $n$ is in the following sequence:

$$1,e,e^e, e^{e^e}, e^{e^{e^e}}, e^{e^{e^{e^e}}}, \cdots$$

---

The inverse Ackermann function $\alpha(n)$ is even slower. For example, consider the powertower $b=e^{e^{e^{e^{\dots}}}}$ with height $10^9$. Then $\log^{*}(n)=10^9+1$, $L(n)=10^9$ but $\alpha(n)=5$.

Comment: Thanks, that what I was looking for. Indeed it' sjust changing $<1$ to $\leq 1$, which I'm perfectly happy with (i stumbled upon this function during an analysis of an algorithm complexity).

Answer (score 1):

It grows very fast compared to the Ackermann function.

Indeed,

$$L( e \uparrow \uparrow n ) = n$$

Where $\uparrow$ is the [Knuth's up arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)